# Configure Elasticsearch Cluster -- Data Dedicated Nodes

Tags: elasticsearch, lucene

I have an elastic search(1.7) cluster that connsist of 21 nodes. I want 15 of them to be dedicated data nodes and other 6 be responsible for querying the data. I have **nod.data = true
nod.master = false** configuration for data nodes. However I am confused with other 6. Should I configure all of them as **nod.data =false nod.master = true** or Is it better to have 3 master eligible node and other 3 will have 
**nod.data = false 
nod.master=true**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have 21 nodes, it's a very good practice to have 3 dedicated master-eligible nodes with a configuration such as this one:

```
node.data: false
node.master: true
```

One of those nodes will be THE elected master node and will be dedicated to manage the cluster state, which with 21 nodes and depending on the load can be quite some work.

Then you can have your 15 data-only nodes with the following configuration:

```
node.data: true
node.master: false
```

Finally, you're left with 3 nodes which you can use as client nodes responsible for querying the data and gathering the results. Those nodes act as some kind of smart load balancers and have the following configuration:

```
node.data: false
node.master: false
```

Comment: Thank you. I am changing my configuration regardingly. I'll let you know the results.

Comment: Hello again, I have changed the configuration. However, the load in machines which have node.data=false attribute is very low(about 0.1). How can I be sure that these are doing their jobs?

Comment: Master nodes can be small machines, no need for a huge amount of RAM or disk. They only need a few CPUs, but if you're cluster is green, then you can be sure that the master node is doing its job. Also the two other master eligible nodes are not doing anything, since they are only there as backup.

Comment: So what about the nodes that serve as life balancer. They also have very low load

Comment: You need to make sure that your client code are hitting those client nodes and not the data nodes directly. If you do and if your load is substantial you'll see that they are pretty active